# Google place auto search on page load doesn't work with dot inside of the URL

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a website that:

1. Loads a Google Map.
2. Gets some value into `input` field with a `$_GET` method that is being used by the Google Places search.
3. Get `autofocus` on the `input` field.
4. Then performs auto search on page load.

The scheme of the links that I can build out of my database data is:

```
example.com?local=52.6762,19.7582 (i.e. lat, lng).
```

The code below works only as long as I am not using a dot sign inside the URL. So for example if I used `example.com?local=52,19` the code would work just as I would like it to work.

But with a link like `example.com?local=52.6,19.7`, it seems to stop on step 3.

I think the bug might be inside part of the code responsible for step 4, i.e.:

```
itemsloaded = google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.body, 'DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
    keyCode: 13
  })
});
```

Maybe you've came across this issue in your projects. Please help.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    #mapindex {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourapikeyhere&libraries=places&types=(cities)"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Google Maps API -->
  <script>
    function initialize() {
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.015460, 18.498087); // Map is centered here  
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
        clickableIcons: false
      };

      function inputFocus() {
        document.getElementById("pac-input").focus();
      }

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapindex"), myOptions);

      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);

      // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });

      var markers = [];
      // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
      // more details for that place.
      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
          if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
          }
          var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          // Create a marker for each place.
          var image = 'http://www.instead.com.pl/target2.png';
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          }));

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });

      // trigger tha autofocus function with timeout
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        // inputFocus();
        setTimeout(inputFocus, 1000);
      });
      // force autosearch on page load
      itemsloaded = google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.body, 'DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
          keyCode: 13
        })
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    function start() {
      initialize();
    }
    window.onload = start;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter location" onload="mouseEnter()" value="<?php if(isset ($_GET['local'])){ echo $_GET['local'];}?>" />
  <div id="mapindex"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And where's the relevant code??

Comment: Sorry but what you mean by relevant?

Comment: You posted dozens of lines of code that are irrelevant to your question. Where's the part where it fails? Your JS code contains PHP variables and we **don't** know what they print. As the close-votes that you received suggest, you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows to reproduce the issue. Read: minimal **and** verifiable (and complete, which doesn't mean we need to see your entire app code).

Comment: Sorry for that. Sometimes I am getting downvotes without any explanation so it is impossible for me to adjust my question. Beleive me this ain't even close to my entire app code. I've put a "copy paste" piece of code prepared especially for this question. Just paste it and add your Google Api key to see it working. Each line is important to see each of the 4 steps working and to reproduce my bug. The code might not be optimal but I don't see any part I could delete. I have edited my question with additional information about my suspicion of where might the bug be.Hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: That can happen for sure. Take it easy, you just need to learn how to post a good question. And you need to learn how to debug your code as well... Check your event for `DOMNodeInserted`. This will trigger a keydown every time a DOM element is added (that is over a hundred times with the code you posted). A simple `console.log` in there could tell you that. Replacing this part with valid code works for me and I do **not** experience the problem you described where if `local` contains dots it stops working... There are other little issues in your code but I won't address these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working and simplified version of your code.

Triggering the focus and keydown on your input field from the map `idle` event is enough. No need to set timeouts, etc.

Also AFAIK, passing `types=(cities)` in the API URL is not valid.

So, if I call this page like this: `map.php?local=52.6762,19.7582`, the map centers on these coords and a marker is displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    #mapindex {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- Google Maps API -->
  <script>
    function initialize() {

      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.015460, 18.498087); // Map is centered here
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
        clickableIcons: false
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapindex"), myOptions);

      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);

      // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });

      var markers = [];
      // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
      // more details for that place.
      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
          if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
          }
          var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          // Create a marker for each place.
          var image = 'http://www.instead.com.pl/target2.png';
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          }));

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });

      // trigger tha autofocus function
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        input.focus();
        google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
          keyCode: 13
        })
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter location" onload="mouseEnter()" value="<?php if (isset ($_GET['local'])) {
      echo $_GET['local'];
    } ?>" />
  <div id="mapindex"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you MrUpsidown for your help. I will optimize my code according to your remarks.

Comment: Great solution, just what I have been searching the whole internet for it. Thanks @MrUpsidown